# How to make parent div grow in height along with its child that has fixed position?

Tags: html, css

i have these 2 divs :

```
<div id="parent" style="border:1px silid;background-color:#fff">
    <div id="child" style="position:fixed;width:100px;height:100px; border:solid 1px;">
    </div> 
</div>
```

Bascally i want the fixed child to stay inside the parent div , so the parent div should resize its height every time the page scrolls down (the child moves down).

Is there a css solution or should i make it in js  ?

Comment: Minor issue: on line one, `style="border:1px silid;"` should be `style="border:1px solid black;"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript should do it.

Don't think css can make it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with CSS (children cannot control parents through CSS, sadly).

You can, however, do this in JavaScript. You can use `.height()` and `.width()` from the parent's perspective, using the value of the child's `.outerHeight()` and `.outerWidth()` as values.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TfNXs/ (*I changed a few things in the styling to make the changes easier to see.*)

Note that I've only done it on page load; you may want to think about `bind`ing that code to any events wherein the `#child`'s size might change.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to apply "overflow: hidden;" to your parent in your CSS. Remove "height" attribute (or set it to "auto"), as well.